# how openstack client get server list with accurate ip address

Tags: list, server, ip-address, openstack

Through openstack client command line tool to get the server list with the accurate ip address not the "--ip <ip-address-regex>", and I used the "--sort-column" and "--limit" optional arguments can't get my expectancy.

Such as the picture, I want to get the only list with the IP "10.17.192.14".

[image]

Comment: The docs say `--ip` uses a regex. You'd need something like `"^10\\.17\\.192\\.14$"`, I think.

Comment: $ doesn't work, I had try

Comment: Seems it's impossible so far. Nova api calls Neutron api to [filter the ip addresses](https://github.com/openstack/nova/blob/926af1faf1e52ae21f60ea1243aa351ff91aaa99/nova/compute/api.py#L3053), but Neutron doesn't support for regex. The logical equals to the command `neutron port-list --fixed-ips ip_address_substr=10.17.192.14`.

Comment: @Ouroborus according to the [code](https://github.com/openstack/nova/blob/926af1faf1e52ae21f60ea1243aa351ff91aaa99/nova/compute/api.py#L2856), it will replace the dot to `\\.` automatically.

Comment: @VictorLee how about using `grep` and add a space after the string, like this `openstack server list |grep "10.17.192.14 "`

Comment: I want to find the answer without using grep or other tools such as sed、 awk, I want to use the only openstack client command.

Comment: I had try all regex which I can find, and it doesn't work.

Comment: It's a bug in OpenStack Nova: https://bugs.launchpad.net/nova/+bug/2006770